# Bounding Taylor coefficients of $f(z)$ with $f(0)=1$, $f(z)\ne 0$ for $|z|\le 1$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f(z)=1+a_1z+\ldots+a_nz^n+\ldots$ be a complex analytic function defined on the unit disk $|z|\le 1$. Suppose $f(z)\ne 0$ for $|z|< 1$. I would like to know what kind statements one can make concerning bounding the absolute values of $a_n$ from above. As the example of $f(z)=(1+z)^n$ shows individual $a_i$ can be as large as you want, but I wonder still if something non-trivial can be said about the set of possible $a_i$. Maybe there are some classical results on this topic?

Comment: What immediately comes to mind is of course 'de Branges's theorem'/'Bieberbach conjecture', but since that theorem requires one *more* assumption (i.e. injectivity), I won't make this an answer.

Comment: More assumptions are needed to give any bounds. This is not a normal family that you consider.

Comment: Your assumption (that the function is defined on the unit disk) implies that the radius of convergence is at least 1, of course, so that you have the bound $a_n=O((1+\epsilon)^n)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: for fixed $i$, $a_i$ may take any value (consider $(1+cz)^n$ for $c\in (0,1)$ and large $n$)

Answer (score 5):

The best conjectured in this generality seems to be the conjecture of Lewandowski and Szynal

*Lewandowski, Zdzisław; Szynal, Jan*, [**The Landau problem for bounded nonvanishing functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(99)00020-5), J. Comput. Appl. Math. 105, No.1-2, 367-369 (1999). [ZBL0945.30011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0945.30011).

They conjecture that for any non-vanishing $f$ in the unit disk such that $|f| < 1$ and any $n$ there exist an $L(n)$ such that $|a_0 + \dotsc + a_n| < L(n).$

As far as I can tell, this is completely open, but some results for small $n$ are known under the additional assumption that the Taylor coefficients are real:

*Koulorizos, Philippos; Samaris, Nikolas*, [**The Landau problem for nonvanishing functions with real coefficients**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(01)00386-7), J. Comput. Appl. Math. 139, No.1, 129-139 (2002). [ZBL1009.30010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1009.30010).

Comment: @PeterHeinig Oops, I missed a hypothesis, you are right.